# OSX: The item XYZ.txt~ can’t be moved to the Trash because it can’t be deleted

Tags: macos

I'm trying to delete a file under OSX Lion, but can't. I get the following message:

> The item XYZ.txt~ can’t be moved to the Trash because it can’t be
>   deleted.

Here's what I've tried:

- select file and press <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd> (I get the message above.)
- renaming the file in finder (There is no option to rename the file.)
- `sudo ls -a` in a terminal (The file does not appear.)
- `sudo rm XYZ.txt~` (I get "No such file or directory".)

How do I remove this file?

---

**EDIT**

The file went away after restarting. My guess is that it was a glitch in finder.

Comment: I've no experience of OSX as such, but bear in mind that when you're running `sudo` from a terminal, it's going to look in the current directory, not necessarily where the file `XYZ.txt~` is. I'm guessing this is the source of your `No such file of directory` errors.

Comment: It sounds like the file is marked read-only or is on a read-only file system (like a Windows NTFS volume). If you right click and get info, does it say you can Read & Write under Sharing and Permissions at the bottom?

Comment: @Andy Smith -- Thanks, but I was running the `sudo` command from the same location as the file.

Comment: @Nick -- When I right click on the file and click get info, nothing happens. The pop-up that usually is supposed to show up (the one that I get with other, more normal files and folders) does not show up.

Comment: It sounds like the file doesn't exist, I don't know why finder would be showing something like that though. What if you try to create a file XYZ.txt~ by typing `touch XYZ.txt~` in that directory in the terminal, then deleting that newly created file?

Answer (score 1):

Try quitting and reopening Finder.

There is a bug where files that no longer exist are still shown on the desktop (but not if you open a separate window for `~/Desktop/`). It has happened to me with `.download` bundles and with temporary files created by ImageMagick. The files have always disappeared after I have quit and reopened Finder.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Finder in such cases?